# Can you boot an Acer Aspire One from an SD card when no BIOS is available?

Tags: boot, bios

Is it possible to boot the [Acer Aspire One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Aspire_One) PC from an [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital)?

I have bricked an Aspire One, but it does not even start the BIOS. Aspire One have this issue and a BIOS update usually work and it helped me once in the past, but this time it's all over, and the BIOS update fails. It still reads the SD card with the magic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut used to launch the BIOS update. Can I trick the computer into booting somehow using this shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aspire One recovery procedure is designed to work from a USB drive, but an SD card should work. You will not be able to boot the machine using the Fn-Esc combination, but you may have another shot at flashing the BIOS by standard procedure (reformat the SD card using FAT, download flashit.exe and the *.fd file for the BIOS in the root of the card, reboot with Fn-Esc)

If the BIOS flash procedure has failed at any point, it is relatively certain that you will be unable to boot the machine in any way until you have flashed the BIOS cleanly.

Comment: all right. sad day for me.